# How to convert this code into function in MATLAB so I may just use it by calling it

Tags: matlab

% Code slightly modified from Signals and Systems by Lathi MS2P4 pg  232.

How can I make this code a function? So that I can just "call" it to use it. Instead of pasting this whole thing over and over. This is just a convolution animation of two functions.

```
figure(1) % Create figure window and make visible on screen 
x = @(t) cos(2*pi*3*t).* u(t);
h = @(t) u(t)-u(t-1);
dtau = 0.005;
tau = -1:dtau:4;
ti = 0;
tvec = -1:0.1:5;
y = NaN*zeros(1,length(tvec)); % Pre-allocate memory
for t = tvec,
    ti = ti + 1; % Time index
    xh = x(t-tau).*h(tau);
    lxh = length(xh);
    y(ti) = sum(xh.*dtau); % Trapezoidal approximation of integral
    subplot(2,1,1)
    plot(tau,h(tau),'k-',tau,x(t-tau),'k--',t,0,'ok')
    axis([tau(1) tau(end) -2.0 2.5])
    patch([tau(1:end-1);tau(1:end-1);tau(2:end);tau(2:end)],...
        [zeros(1,lxh-1);xh(1:end-1);xh(2:end);zeros(1,lxh-1)],...
        [0.8 0.8 0.8],'edgecolor','none')
    xlabel('\tau')
    legend('h(\tau)','x(t-\tau)','t','h(\tau)x(t-\tau)')
    c = get(gca,'children');
    set(gca,'children',[c(2);c(3);c(4);c(1)]);
    subplot(2,1,2)
    plot(tvec,y,'k',tvec(ti),y(ti),'ok')
    xlabel('t')
    ylabel('y(t) = \int h(\tau)x(t-\tau) d\tau')
    axis([tau(1) tau(end) -1.0 2.0])
    grid
    drawnow
%   pause
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Matlab's `function` , as described [here](http://www.mathworks.es/help/matlab/ref/function.html)

So, you have to write on the top "function yourFunctionName" and then you can call it using its name, `yourFunctionName` in this case.

Comment: function convol_anime(x,h). I stared with that to create my function. when I put in two arbitrary functions x(t) and h(t) (same as above) the animation graph isn't showing. how come? I called it by convol_anime(x(t),h(t)) for the respective x(t) and h(t) above

Comment: got it by removing the (t), so just inputs x,y

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked with your exact code, a straightforward function definition and the addition of `u(t)` that was missing from the OP:

```
figure(1) % figure window outside function
u = @(t)heaviside(t); % define step function
x = @(t) cos(2*pi*3*t).* u(t);
h = @(t) u(t)-u(t-1);
dtau = 0.005;

convol_anime(x, h, dtau); % pass function handles + parameters
```

where you have already defined:

```
function convol_anime(x, h, dtau)

tau = -1:dtau:4; ti = 0; tvec = -1:0.1:5;
y = nan*zeros(1,length(tvec)); 
...
```